# jasper reports does not display report in Japanese

Tags: java, encoding, jasper-reports

I have a problem regarding the jasper reports. I have already an application that will generate a report using jasper reports. It does fine when my PC's Region and Language setting, the Format is not in Japanese even though the characters are in Japanese. But when I change my Format to Japanese, there comes the problem. It will generate a report thou but there is no display. We can tell that it can't generate a report because a message will appear saying "The Document has no page". Does this have something to do with the encoding or fonts?

The Japanese characters were also not displayed in the PDF that was generated.

Comment: Are you using query in a report? Are you checking report with *iReport*?

Comment: do you mean this one? 
<queryString>
  <![CDATA[SELECT xxxxxxxxxx]>
 </queryString>

Comment: Are you using the [Font Extensions](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/fonts/index.html) mechanism? What is your *JR* version?

Comment: the query? 
here:
 <queryString>
  <![CDATA[SELECT PRODUCTS.REFERENCE, PRODUCTS.NAME, PRODUCTS.PRICESELL, PRODUCTS.CATEGORY, CATEGORIES.NAME AS CATEGORYNAME, TAXES.NAME AS TAXNAME, TAXES.RATE AS TAXRATE
FROM PRODUCTS LEFT OUTER JOIN CATEGORIES ON PRODUCTS.CATEGORY = CATEGORIES.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN TAXES ON PRODUCTS.TAX = TAXES.ID
ORDER BY PRODUCTS.CATEGORY]]>
 </queryString>

Comment: i've downloaded the jasperreports 3.5.2 jar and included it in my class path

Answer (score 0):

Check your .jrxml report file has this header;

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: I have that in my header already. Still nothing.
Does this have something to do with updating my jasperreport.jar?

Comment: @lawrence Add jasperreports-fonts-x.x.x.jar to project's classpath.

Comment: it worked in the preview! thanks. but now, when i checked the generated pdf, the japanese characters were not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to solve my problem with the help of the above answers. 
What I did was, I updated my jasperreports.jar and iText.. Also, i've added itextasian.jar and jasperreports-font.jar (with the help above). 
In my jrxml files, i've changed fonts and encoding to:

```
                pdfFontName="HeiseiKakuGo-W5" pdfEncoding="UniJIS-UCS2-H"
```